# Tensorflow distributed training with custom training step

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, sparse-matrix, tensorflow-datasets

I am facing slow training runs and I have tried to scale up the training procedure by using Tensorflow's `Strategy` API to utilize all 4 GPUs.

I'm using `MirrorStrategy` and using `experimental_distribute_dataset` to partition the dataset.

Nature of my training data is a mix of both sparse matrices and dense matrices. [I'm using a generator to construct my dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) (**which picks random indices to pick from the data**). However, in my current version of TF (2.1) [generators don't support sparse matrices](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/41981). The `sparse_matrix` does not have a static size and is a `Ragged` tensor.

This bit is ugly and a workaround, but I'm passing my `sparse_matrix_list` directly to the `train` function, and index into it by having a global queue that gets populated by pushing the random indices inside `generator`.

Now this approach was working fine, but it was way too slow, and I wanted to try training with all GPUs. This gets even more problematic as I have to manually partition the `sparse_matrix_list` into `num_workers` splits.

However, the main problem right now is that the training procedure does not seem to be **parallel** and the **replicas (GPUs) seem to be running sequentially.**. I verified this through `nvidia-smi` and logs in the `train_process` function.

I have no prior experience with distributed training, and not sure why this would be the case, and I would really appreciate it if someone has pointers for a better way of handling this mix of `spare` and `dense` data. I'm currently facing a huge bottleneck in fetching my data which underutilizes the GPUs (fluctuates between 10-30%)

```
def distributed_train_step(inputs, sparse_matrix_list):
    per_replica_losses = strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_process, args=(inputs, sparse_matrix_list)
    return strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                                axis=None)


def train_process(inputs, sparse_matrix_list):
    worker_id = tf.distribute.get_replica_context().replica_id_in_sync_group
    replica_batch_size = inputs.shape[0]
    slice_start = replica_batch_size * worker_id
    replica_sparse_matrix = sparse_matrix_list[slice_start:slice_start + replica_batch_size]

    return train_step(inputs, replica_sparse_matrix)


def train_step(inputs, sparse_matrix_list):
     with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
           outputs, mu, sigma, feat_out, logit = model(inputs)
           loss = K.backend.mean(custom_loss(inputs, sparse_matrix_list)

     return loss

def get_batch_data(sparse_matrix_list):
    # Queue with the random indices into the training data (List of Lists with each 
    # entry len == batch_size)
    # train_indicie is a global q
    next_batch_indicies = train_indicies.get()

    batch_sparse_list = sparse_matrix_list[next_batch_indicies]
            

dist_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)

for batch, inputs in enumerate(dist_dataset, 1):
    # sparse_matrix_list is passed to this main "train" function from outside this module.
    batch_sparse_matrix_slice = get_batch_data(sparse_matrix_list)

    loss = distributed_train_step(inputs, batch_sparse_matrix_slice)
```